# Is there a way to visualize border edges of meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh

When editing a mesh, it sometimes happens that two faces are seemingly connected by an edge, but these are actually two edges on top of each other. Often enough I only notice this way later. For example when moving one of the faces, revealing the hole in the mesh.

In Maya there was an option to highlight border edges. Does Blender has something similar?

Or this there another workflow in Blender to detect gaps?

Comment: would an wire frame help? here is a link to a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAaToapgBxQ

Comment: A screenshot (or a gif of mesh close-up revealed) probably could help since *"these are actually two edges on top of each other"* seems like simple removing doubles would be enough. There is selecting borders tool, select all and run Boundary Loop from Edges menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean **check non-manifold**?

Type `select non manifold` in search-bar (<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>) in verts select mode(edit mode) when selecting nothing.

It will help you to select something not manifold including separated holes

[image]

Comment: This is a neat feature, how come it’s not listed in any menu? Or am I just blind?

Comment: This is a very handy function, and quite close to what I'm looking for. I tried it and as expected it will select a lot more parts than just border edges.

Comment: @mic.. It's under (Header) > Select > Select All by Trait > Non-Manifold. It's also worth checking the options in the operator, to narrow the selection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I’m gonna be using this a lot :)

Comment: Please don't just add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Comment: Manifold is a special trait that we always want. A lot of algorithm in 3D need a manifold mesh to operate. It is a common thing in computer graphic, and there should be a similar one in others program.

Answer (score 3):

A quick option is sometimes *Select Similar* in Edge Mode. Select an edge known to be on a boundary to nothing, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > 'Amount of Faces Around an Edge' to select the others.

Comment: So I need to have a border in order to use this function. Other than that this is what I'm looking for. Is there something like 'select border edges'?

Comment: @mic it's one of the check-box options in _Select Non Manifold_  as described in the other answer. The settings will persist on repeat usage, in any one session, until you change them.